# Is there any way to put a JavaScript embed/content inside Xamarin Forms for WebViews?

Tags: javascript, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, tableau-api

I'm new to Xamarin. I'm making a project using MasterPages that shows some of my Tableau Dashboards and before I never had trouble using ASP.NET to insert this kind of Dashboards.

I want to know whether it is possible to put inside my content pages using XamarinForms a Dashboard from Tableau Public, seems like it uses a JS API for that.

Here is the code itself:

```
<div class='tableauPlaceholder' id='viz1586875192729' style='position: relative'>
    <noscript>
        <a href='#'>
            <img alt=' ' src='https:&#47;&#47;public.tableau.com&#47;static&#47;images&#47;Da&#47;DashboardEBITDAEFATURAMENTO1_0_3revfinal&#47;Painel4&#47;1_rss.png' style='border: none' />
        </a>
    </noscript>
    <object class='tableauViz'  style='display:none;'>
        <param name='host_url' value='https%3A%2F%2Fpublic.tableau.com%2F' />
        <param name='embed_code_version' value='3' />
        <param name='site_root' value='' />
        <param name='name' value='DashboardEBITDAEFATURAMENTO1_0_3revfinal&#47;Painel4' />
        <param name='tabs' value='no' />
        <param name='toolbar' value='yes' />
        <param name='static_image' value='https:&#47;&#47;public.tableau.com&#47;static&#47;images&#47;Da&#47;DashboardEBITDAEFATURAMENTO1_0_3revfinal&#47;Painel4&#47;1.png' />
        <param name='animate_transition' value='yes' />
        <param name='display_static_image' value='yes' />
        <param name='display_spinner' value='yes' />
        <param name='display_overlay' value='yes' />
        <param name='display_count' value='yes' />
    </object>
</div>

<script type='text/javascript'>
var divElement = document.getElementById('viz1586875192729');                    
var vizElement = divElement.getElementsByTagName('object')[0];                   

if ( divElement.offsetWidth > 800 ) { vizElement.style.width='1100px';vizElement.style.height='627px';} 
else if ( divElement.offsetWidth > 500 ) { vizElement.style.width='1100px';vizElement.style.height='627px';} 
else { vizElement.style.width='100%';vizElement.style.height=(divElement.offsetWidth*1.77)+'px';}                    

var scriptElement = document.createElement('script');                    
scriptElement.src = 'https://public.tableau.com/javascripts/api/viz_v1.js';
vizElement.parentNode.insertBefore(scriptElement, vizElement);
</script>
```

The only thing that I could actually get was to make a WebView inside XAML and then insert the source website URL like this:

```
<ContentPage.Content>
    <StackLayout>
        <WebView x:Name="Browser"></WebView>
    </StackLayout>
</ContentPage.Content>
```

And then at my CS I did this

```
public FaturamentoView()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    Browser.WidthRequest = 1000;
    Browser.HeightRequest = 1000;
    Browser.Source = "https://public.tableau.com/profile/fernando3479#!/vizhome/RelatrioFATURAMENTO1_0_2/RelatrioFaturamento";
```

But still it is only showing a web visualization, what I want is to use the JS code, is there any way?

Comment: Have you try to put it into local,then you load it from `file:///android_asset/ ` refer to  [Local HTML Content](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/webview?tabs=macos#android)

Comment: Hi, can you give me a sample on how to do that? I was trying to figure it out still couldn't do it

Comment: There is a sample in the link above,or you could try to use `HtmlWebViewSource` to load the html,(e.g. `string content = @“<html> ...... </html>”;var htmlsource = new HtmlWebViewSource(); htmlsource.Html = content ; webview.Source = htmlsource;`)